# Ubuntu 18.04 Partition my harddrive with GParted after installing the OS

Tags: partitioning, gparted, 18.04

I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Internal Harddisk with 500 GB
- External Harddisk with 4 TB (not important for my problem)

The internal harddisk shows the following properties with the GParted app:

Sidebar: "Device Information":

- Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-7
- Serial: WD-WCC2EEY94064
- Size: 465.76 GiB
- Path: /dev/sda
- Partion table: msdos
- Heads: 255
- Secotrs/track: 63
- Cyclinders: 60801
- Total sectors: 976773168
- Sector size: 512

Partition > Manage Flags > Popup: "Manage flags on /dev/sda1"

- boot (checked)
- lvm (checked)

Partition > Information > Popup: "Information about /dev/sda1"

- /dev/sda1
- 465.76 GiB

  File System
- File system: lvm2.pv
- Label:
- UUID: hJASV0-k01i-3Eqj-9gXc-8sa4-yqR4-MajmGz
- Status: Active
- Volume Group: ubuntu-vg
- Members: /dev/sda1
- Logical Volumes: "/dev/sda1" and "swap_1"
- Used: 465.76 GiB ( 100% )
- Unused: 4.00 MiB ( 0% )
- Size: 465.76 GiB

  Partition:
- Path: /dev/sda1
- Name:
- Flags: boot, lvm
- First sector: 2048
- Last sector: 976771071
- Total sectors: 976769024

Partition > Resize/Move > Popup: "Resize /dev/sda1"

- Minimum size: 476934 MiB
- Free space preceding (MiB): 0
- Maximum size: 476939 MiB
- New size (MiB): 476938
- Free space following (MiB): 1
- Align to: MiB

View > File System Support > Popup "File System Support":

- File System: lvm2.pv
- Create: checked
- Grow: checked checked
- Shrink: checked checked
- Move: checked
- Copy: X
- Check: checked
- Label: X
- UUID: X
- Required Software: lvm2

At the moment, I am using about 7 GB of the harddisk. The installation is new and during the installation I chose my 500 GB harddisk for installation, but I didn't make any partitions, because I wasn't sure how to do it. I was hoping to do it now. But it is not very intuitive. I assume that the 7 GB data is not spread all over my harddisk and therefore I can still split it into two partitions:

1. OS (50 GB)
2. DATA (the rest of the harddisk)

Could you give me some pointers on how to proceed? Do I need additional software? Any help appreciated.

Comment: By the way, I just tried my CD and use "Try Ubuntu" to use GParted, but it didn't help. I can't resize my partition. There is a 1 MB unallocated space, the rest is one big 465 GB piece, that I can't resize at all.

Comment: You can't resize the partition if it's mounted (shows a key icon). There could be other reasons. Edit your question and include a screenshot.

Comment: I got a little further. I booted with my usb stick and then I used the following command: sudo lvremove /dev/ubuntu-vg/root and then in gparted I could deactivate the drive and for the first time I got to resize the partition, but the action was never successfully executed I got an error message from gparted:

Comment: lvm pvresize -v --setphysicalvolumesize 51200000K '/dev/sda1'  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
      
0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
Wiping internal VG cache
Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
Archiving volume group "ubuntu-vg" metadata (seqno 5).
/dev/sda1: Requested size <48.83 GiB is less than real size <465.76 GiB. Proceed? [y/n]: [n]
Physical Volume /dev/sda1 not resized.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about LVM, have never used it. Hopefully someone more knowledgable will come along.

Comment: @OrganicMarble If I reinstall the whole os and then during installation choose to make partitions, what file system would you recommend? ext4 for both the partitions?

Comment: That's what I do.  Ext4 partitions for /, /home, and I've been setting up a swap partition, but I understand that for 18.04 it's not required.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I just reinstalled the whole thing and made it ext4. According some other post on this site.

Comment: I`m with the same problem but I can`t simply format everything. Just stuck with GParted not working and even when running (successfully) using command line pvresize won`t work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044601/gparted-cant-shrink-physical-volume

Comment: @Bernhard I understand that you already solved your situation, but it's being caused by a change in pvresize not expected by GParted. Same link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044601/gparted-cant-shrink-physical-volume/1044629#1044629